# How to one way sync from server to client while reducing server load?

Tags: file-synchronization

I'm trying to find a solution for this problem.

1. Server has some files it changes over time. Clients have to sync it with only read permission. Clients are not allowed to write to server.
2. Also to reduce server load: if 1 or more clients have newest version of files all local clients should sync from those up to date clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what [BitTorrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bittorrent) is for.

1. Seed the file from your server. Set a low upload limit.
2. Connect the the BitTorrent clients to this seed. Data will first be downloaded from the server, but then mostly exchanged between peers, as the peers will have higher upload limits.

Comment: can it be shared to clients without write permission?

Comment: Yes, clients don't write to the server.

Comment: What would happen if those files are dll's and executables And clients are executing some of it?

Comment: @user3859522: They would execute normally, as they would on the server.